# How to train a model for new/poorly performing objects in object detection?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, tensorflow-datasets

I have successfully trained an object detection model using a faster-rcnn model found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection).

I roughly understand (conceptually) how to create train vs eval datasets by taking 30% of my training data and using it as the "ground truth" for evaluation. I also have a good grasp on using checkpoints and saving/exporting models as a starting point to refine training.

In my dataset (only 2 classes) - one of the classes is present about 95% of the time, while the other is very seldom present in video. This has led to a model that detects class 1 very very well, but it has low confidence detections, or no detections at all for class 2.

I'm creating a dataset that represents class 2 more often to improve training, but overall as I iterate on the model, what do I do with my existing datasets? My concern is that if I replace the training or eval datasets, my model will forget how to detect class 1.

Do I just add more images to both train/eval? Do I replace the training set entirely for this iteration and just add a chunk to eval?

Comment: I would train again the neural network using a balanced dataset (union of the first dataset and the second dataset).

Comment: @TommasoBendinelli - so keep old data and just add to both training and eval? do I need my old training data?

Comment: Join all the data (old training+validation, new training+validation), randomly shuffle it and then use one fourth or one fifth for validation and the rest for training.